# Sending identity to controller post action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 displaybutton">
        <div data-point-to="displaysHeader">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Administration", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <button id="btnAdministration" type="button" style="width:150px;height:50px;background-color:white;color:blue;border:none;font-size:medium" onclick="return GotoAdminstration();">Administration</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 displaybutton">
        <div data-point-to="pagesHeader">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Indexes", "Meeting", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <button id="btnMeetingSchedule" type="submit" style="width:150px;height:50px;background-color:white;color:blue;border:none;font-size:medium" onclick="return ShowOverlay();">Meeting Schedule</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the JavaScript for this page:

```
var user;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //debugger;
    user = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) }();
```

And then when I try to post:

```
function GotoAdminstration() {
    ShowOverlay();
    var form = $('<form method="POST" action="@Url.Action("Administration","Home")">');
    form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="ident" value="' + user + '">'));
    $(body).append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Bu the action parameter is always null.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is it you wanting to achieve here? What is the point of sending a model to a view and then sending it all back again unchanged (you already know what it is on the server so your just degrading performance). And you have bound a javascript object to the hidden input, not a c# model, so you would then need to deserialize the value of the hidden input in the POST method. Just pass back the ID of the model (as a route parameter in the form (no inputs, no scripts) and get it again in the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

In your cshtml file include a script tag like this

```
<script>
     var urlString='@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Administration","Home"))';
</script>
```

then try using this in your javaScript file:

```
var form = $('<form method="POST" action="'+urlString+'">');
```

Comment: When I remove the plus signs, I still get an error on the additional quote.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use entire `form` tag as selector, you can just add an `id` attribute to the form and use it as selector:

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Administration", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "adminform" }))
{
    // form contents
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#adminform').submit();
```

Note that `append`ing hidden `input` element before submitting form sounds like not a good idea (you need to deserialize it first). Try using a viewmodel property and `HiddenFor` helper inside the form instead (also I preferred using jQuery `click` event instead of `onclick`):

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Administration", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "adminform" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ident)
    <button id="btnAdministration" type="button" style="width:150px;height:50px;background-color:white;color:blue;border:none;font-size:medium">Administration</button>
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#btnAdministration').click(function () {
    ShowOverlay();
    $('#Ident').val(user); // add 'user' variable content inside hidden field
    $('#adminform').submit();
});
```